# MyPy Type Check Decorated Class

Tags: python, decorator, mypy

This is a simplified version of a class decorator I've written. It functions as expected, but mypy doesn't like it, complaining that FormB and FormA do not inherit from FormBase. How do I convince mypy that this code is okay?

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Any


class FormBase(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def fn(self) -> str:
        pass

def form(cls: type[Any]) -> type[FormBase]:
    class NewClass(FormBase):
        def fn(self) -> str:
            return cls.__name__
    return NewClass

@form
class FormA:
    pass

@form
class FormB:
    pass


forms : list[type[FormBase]] = [FormA, FormB]

for f in forms:
    print(f().fn())
```

Comment: I was able to work around this by changing `@form` to decorate just the run function instead of the whole class, but I'd still like to know how to solve this if necessary

Comment: You cannot, at least without `mypy` plugin. You need Intersection type which now only on "suggested" stage, not implemented and no PEP is written. See [this issue](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213) for reference. You may try [`basedmypy`](https://github.com/KotlinIsland/basedmypy) that has limited `Intersection` support.